# Changing boolean value in another method?

Tags: java, netbeans, methods, boolean

When I use the following code in Java 8 within NetBeans it doesn't seem to work well. For example, in one method I create the following:

```
boolean isGuessCorrect = true;
```

It is then passed to another method where it can be used. However, if I then have some conditional statement that changes the value it doesn't work. NetBeans actually tells me that it can't be changed. Instead I am forced to use something like this:

```
int isGuessCorrect = 1;
```

When I use that approach, treating 1 as true and 0 as false, I have no problems changing the values of the variables and passing them around as needed.

The problem is that, for readability, I would prefer using true/false rather than using digits to store the true/false conditions. Is there something special about them that keeps it from working the way I want?

**EDIT:** This is a very simple text based game that uses logical control of methods and passing variables to handle events in the game.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
        //Sets the game status and difficulty.
        //Using as a separate method so I don't have these variables overwritten on subsequent runs.
        int newGame = 1;
        int difficulty = 6;
        game_menu1(newGame, difficulty);        
}
```

The above is what I currently have to use, however, what I initially attempted was:

```
        boolean newGame = true;
```

The idea is that, depending on if the game is new or not, different things would occur.

In a later part of the program:

```
        public static void game_menu2(int newGame, int difficulty, int digit1, int digit2, int choice, int counter)
{
    newGame = 0;
```

The above is what I am currently using. I change the 1 to 0 to indicate that the game is no longer new. However, if I used

```
        public static void game_menu2(boolean newGame, int difficulty, int digit1, int digit2, int choice, int counter)
{
    newGame = false;
```

It doesn't work. I'm sorry, but I would have to change a great deal more since I reference this in several places before I can get the exact error message.

**EDIT 2**: hmm. Even though I had the problem a few hours ago and last night, after changing the code to use boolean variables where needed I am not seeing the same error code. It's likely that the problem I had was something unrelated, a bug that just looked like it was an issue with boolean itself. It's also possible that I had a final operator in place previously where I am not currently using it. Even though I am very familiar with other languages, I am still learning Java in a classroom setting.

I would accept as a correct answer anyone that can show me the situations where this type of problem would normally be expected to occur.

Comment: No, you should be able to reassign a non final boolean variable. Can you show what you tried?

Comment: Could you please post the complete code? I'm not sure if I got what you wanna mean...

Comment: Is the method parameter using the `final` modifier?

Comment: We need to see more code.  I'm not sure where you've declared either of those variables, and your situation would make more sense if that were clear to us.

Comment: So you are saying that you want to send a `boolean`, a local var in one method to another method where it is mutated. 
You could try wrapping the `boolean` in an Object and sending it.

Comment: Sure, but I'll have to redo a bit of code to get back to that error I was one. One sec and I'll edit.

Comment: @Makoto What do you mean "I'm not sure where you've declared either of those variables" - As I stated in the question, I declared them in one method, passed to another method, and tried to change it in that other method.

Comment: ...and that's why I want to see the actual code.  You passed them *both* to another method?  That doesn't make sense; Java would complain about a redeclaration of `isGuessCorrect`.  If you don't mind, would you please include the code?  You'll get more help (and we'll be able to see better context) if you do.

Comment: Thanks for posting some code, but I need *more* context.  What part doesn't work?  Is it a compilation error?  Is it a runtime error?  Including the full body of the method would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, arguments are [passed by reference](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm) - or, to be more exact, [*object references* are passed by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

An exception is made for primitives like `int`, `double`, and... `bool`, which are passed by value.

Thus,

```
public static void game_menu2(boolean newGame, int difficulty, int digit1, int digit2, int choice, int counter)
{
    newGame = false;
```

operates on a *local copy* of newGame which dies with the function.

Any change made to `newGame` (or `difficult`, `digit1`... for that matter) ***only* applies to the local copy** and is not visible outside your method.

The [`Boolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) class, as any other class, can be passed by reference; unfortunately `Boolean` is [immutable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html), so you can't do much with it.

I'd consider wrapping your `bool` inside a (mutable) class

```
class BooleanWrapper {
    public bool value
}
```

and passing that around instead.

**Note, however, that I can think of few situations in which passing a `bool` reference is a good idea, and your is probably not one of them:** if I understand your use case correctly, I would just update your flag by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Because Java passes arguments by reference, changing the value of a parameter does not change the variable which was used to press a value into that variable. You have at least two alternatives.

1. Create a class member to hold the value.
2. Return the new value and do an assignment in the caller method.